# Codeignitter 404 not found on replicated folder but works on original folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, xampp

My code was working well before i copied the code folder so that i can reuse my codes for another project. Everything is copied as is and renamed the folder to abc from xyz(abc and xyz files exist in same folder- htdocs-Xamp server). If i try to access from `localhost/abc/admin/Code/index.php/main/author` it works but if i remove `index.php` from above url it gives 404 error. but in xyz folder everything works fine with or without `index.php` in url. I have copied exact `.htaccess` file from xyz folder to abc foolder.

I use xampp server to run my codes.

my .htaccess file is as under

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

my config.php file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/abc/admin/Code/';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

my routes.php file

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Main';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: in previous folder name was it working without index.php?

Comment: Yes it is working in prev folder.

Comment: can u add your controllers folder structure??

Comment: Codeigniter home directory > applications > controllers > Main.php